# How to Target Another Element via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

My jDeveloper version is **11.1.1.9.0**

I'm aware of targeting an element via the `clientListener` tag. But that will give me a reference to only the element in which it was declared. What if I want to target another element on the page based on it's ID declared in jDeveloper? For example:

```
<af:inputText label="Label 1" clientComponent="true" id="it15"> // what's declared in jDeveloper
```

Which renders into HTML as:

```
<input type="text" class="x25" name="r1:0:it15" id="r1:0:it15::content">
```

Notice how `it15` gets converted into `r1:0:it15`. So doing the following fails in getting a reference to the element:

```
document.getElementById("it15"); // returns null  
AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent("it15"); // returns undefined
```

This brings me to the following questions:

1. Why does the ID change when the HTML gets rendered?
2. How would I target the element if its ID gets prepend-ed by a random
   string?
3. Is there a way to fetch that random string instead of hardcoding it
   with the control ID?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps but i have faced similar issue with ado.net and there was a way to add snippet to get client id.

Comment: Your input text is in a form called r1 and it looks like you are creating multiple inputTexts based on the 0 via repeat or something similar. Jsf translates your fields ID into something unique so that it can be found.

Comment: That makes sense. Yes I do have more textboxes in the form. But the form id is `f1` and its first child's ID is `r1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query selector if you're sticking with just a straight DOM:

```
document.querySelector('[id$=it15]')
```

Comment: I just tested it. It is returning a reference to it's parent, i.e. `tr` but not the element itself

Comment: Oh, I see.  I was going on your initial revision.  I didn't realize initially that there was more being appended to the id (I am not familiar with the framework you're using but it sounds like you might be close with AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent.  You might need to qualify it with a parent ID?

Comment: Well, you put me in the right path with the use of `querySelector`. So thanks for that. But I'm hoping to get the recommended way of going about it. Upvoted.